# Continuous function with negative derivative when it is equal to zero

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

The following statement seems very intuitive but I can't find a proof nor am I sure how to prove it rigorously:

If the derivative of a continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with **$f(0)=0$** is nonpositive whenever $f$ is equal to zero, i.e., $f(t)=0$ implies $f'(t) \leq 0$, then it must be that $f(t) \leq 0$ for all $t$.

Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

**Update:** The above statement does not hold but it seems that assuming $f(t)=0$ implies $f'(t)<0$ or a weaker version would make the statement true. I'm looking for a positive result!

Comment: You are talking about the derivative of a continuous function. Continuous function aren't differentiable in general. Do you mean a differentiable function instead?

Comment: You'd need $f(t) = 0 \implies f'(t) < 0$, otherwise look at $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$ for suitable $\alpha$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to assume $f'(0)<0$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer (the right derivative)

Comment: It is not enough to assume $f'(0)<0.$ Consider $f(x)=x^2-x.$

Comment: @mfl In your example $f(1)=0$ but  $f'(1)=1>0$

Comment: @DanielFischer I meant $f'(0)<0$ and $f(t)=0$ implies $f'(t) \leq 0$ for $t>0$

Comment: Still: take for example $(t-2)^3$, and modify it on $[0,1]$ in such a way that you get a function with $f(0) = 0,\, f'(0) < 0$ and $f(t) < 0$ for $0 < t < 2$.

Comment: Do you mean a function like. 1- cos (x) ???

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I think the original statement needs a condition on the second derivative (nonpositive?) to hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption $f(t)=0\implies f'(t)<0$ one has that $f(t)<0,\forall t\in (0,\infty).$ We will argue by contradiction. Let $x_0$ be the smallest positive real number such that $f(x_0)=0.$ (It exists because $f'(0)<0$ implies that $f$ is negative in some interval $(0,\epsilon)$.) Now, in the interval $[0,x_0]$ the function has two maximum values: at $0$ and $x_0.$ So, since $f(x_0)=0$ and $f'(x_0)<0$ this is not possible. Why? Because $f'(x_0^-)\ge 0.$ This gives us the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(t) = t^3$$ seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: $f(t)=t^2$ also works.